# we define $Ax=\{ \eta_i \}_{i=1}^{\infty},$ where $\eta_i=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{ij}\xi_j, \ (i=1,2,\ldots),$ Compute $\|A \|$.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

Assume that $(a_{ij})_{i,j=1}^{\infty}$ is a matrix satisfying the following condition
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^{\infty} |a_{ij}|^q<\infty \ (q>1),$$
where $x=\{\xi_j \}_{j=1}^{\infty} \in l_p$, $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$, we define
$$Ax=\{ \eta_i \}_{i=1}^{\infty},$$
where
$$\eta_i=\sum_{j=1}^{\infty} a_{ij}\xi_j, \ (i=1,2,\ldots),$$
Compute $\|A \|$.

Using Holder inequality we can obtain
$$\| Ax\| \leq \|x\| \left(\sum_{i,j=1}^{\infty} |a_{ij}|^q \right)^{1/q}$$
Now, I want to choose $x_0 \in l_p$ such that $\|x_0 \|=1$ and
$$\|Ax_0 \|\geq \left(\sum_{i,j=1}^{\infty} |a_{ij}|^q \right)^{1/q}$$
Could you please give me some suggestions for $x_0$? Thank you so much.

Comment: how exactly did you apply Holder's inequality? shouldn't that be $\sum_i \left (    \sum_j|a_{ij}|^q \right )^{1/q}$?. Regardless, for $x_o$  look where Holder achieves equality.